# Drafting a question on new SE site, then linking accounts, does not recover the full draft

Tags: bug, asking-questions, draft

I was composing a question on DBA without realising that as a new user there I would need to link my network account.

The post editor [automatically saves post drafts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333249/the-form-on-the-ask-question-page-is-filled-with-a-question-which-ive-already), but when I linked my account to DBA, the question edit page reappeared, but *with only the very first line of the question text present.* The large majority was lost.

The tag I entered also disappeared.

(Luckily, I chose to copy the text before submitting.)

Comment: The draft didn't save again before you navigated away.

Comment: It was a long post (some 120 lines) and took several tens of minutes to type out and gather information to include. Shouldn't the draft have auto-saved several times? And shouldn't there be a "strong warning" that logging in will potentially lose information?

Comment: Eh, don't trust the auto-save features. There's always a chance you'll lose some data if you leave. Just make sure you back it up offline periodically, or even type it offline

Comment: I wasn't really relying on auto-save. I made a reasonable (I think?) assumption that if a form invited me to log in, it would log me in, then present the same form with the same data on it. Should really be made more clear that work will be lost if part of the posting process requires login.

Comment: @Zoe: Indeed, never trust anything to a web interface to not be lost. The browsers are better at remembering these days, but save retyping by copy-pasting from a local text document.